# How to evaluate only a part of a lazy sequence?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Lazy evaluation is a great boon for stuff like processing huge files that will not fit in main memory at one go. However, suppose there are some elements in the sequence that I want evaluated immediately, while the rest can be lazily computed - is there any way to specify that?

*Specific problem: (in case that helps to answer the question)*

Specifically, I am using a series of IEnumerables as iterators for multiple sequences - these sequences are data read from files opened using BinaryReader streams (each sequence is responsible for the reading in of data from one of the files). The MoveNext() on these is to be called in a specific order. Eg. `iter0` then `iter1` then `iter5` then `iter3` .... and so on. This order is specified in another  sequence `index` = `{0,1,5,3,....}`. However sequences being lazy, the evaluation is naturally done only when required. Hence, the file reads (for the sequences right at the beginning that read from files on disk) happens as the IEnumerables for a sequence are moving. This is causing an illegal file access - a file that is being read by one process is accessed again (as per the error msg).

True, the illegal file access could be for other reasons, and after having tried my best to debug other causes a partially lazy evaluation might be worth trying out.

Comment: If you're only reading from a file, then there should be no problem with havin multiple streams that read the file at the same time. You cuold try using some caching mechanism (evaluate a part of sequence eagerly), but there should be no need for that since the file system uses buffers anyway.

Comment: How are you opening the file? You may need to use [`FileShare.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileShare.aspx).

Comment: @TomasPetricek and Daniel : spot on with the file read sharing, thanks a lot. ages of `fopen("foo.bar","r")` made me forget that `FileMode.Open` doesn't mean others can read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree with Tomas' comment: you shouldn't need this if file sharing is handled properly, here's one way to eagerly evaluate the first *N* elements:

```
let cacheFirst n (items: seq<_>) =
  seq {
    use e = items.GetEnumerator()
    let i = ref 0
    yield! 
      [ 
        while !i < n && e.MoveNext() do
          yield e.Current
          incr i
      ]
    while e.MoveNext() do
      yield e.Current
  }
```

Example

```
let items = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> printfn "%d" i; i)

items
|> Seq.take 10
|> cacheFirst 5
|> Seq.take 3
|> Seq.toList
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
val it : int list = [0; 1; 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's solution is sound, but I don't think we need another operator, just `Seq.cache` for most cases.

First cache your sequence:

```
let items = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> printfn "%d" i; i) |> Seq.cache
```

Eager evaluation followed by lazy access from the beginning:

```
let eager = items |> Seq.take 5 |> Seq.toList
let cached = items |> Seq.take 3 |> Seq.toList
```

This will evaluate the first 5 elements once (during `eager`) but make them cached for secondary access.

Comment: If his files are large `Seq.cache` is going to use a lot of memory since it keeps all enumerated items around.

Comment: `Seq.cache` solved the file read error problem. but yeah, the file sizes are quite large - larger than physical memory capacity.